# Wordpress Website not responding after I made changes in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I was making few changes in function.php file in wordpress.After I saved the file my wordpress site stopped responding. None of the pages or admin panel is opening.It's showing error 500. It just turned white. I have came across many solutions suggesting Filezilla. But I didn't used Filezilla earlier to upload my files. Now when my site is down and I am trying to connect it using Filezilla, It is not connecting. Please suggest what should I do ? Does the error temporary or should I forcefully do something to make it run? I need to fix it soon.

Edit: The problem arised when I tried to make change in the following code of function.php:

```
add_image_size('xlarge-thumbnail', 1280, 1080, false);
```

In the above code in place of dimensions (1280, 1080) , I tried to give (100%,100%). After that whole site went blank

Comment: First start by reading the logs... What is FileZilla telling you when you try to connect? 500 error means that an internal error happened and you'll have to check server logs for what has happened.

Comment: can you provide your function.php files code??

Comment: have u tried to delete the code u added and check again?

Comment: the logs is telling                                                                              Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:         Could not connect to server

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How do I delete my code if I can't open my admin panel

Comment: you can connect using ftp client @UditGogoi then go to functions.php its not a good idea, editing function straight from admin panel

Comment: I have edited my question to add extra info please check through it

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That's what I am trying to do. Using FIlezilla also I am not being able to connect.

Comment: try going to your website clientarea then use filamanager of Cpanel and navigate to files@UditGogoi

Comment: www.xyz.com/wp-admin ; this link isn't working. @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: @UditGogoi control panel, those details were given to you by your hosting provider when you purchased the hosting package

Answer (score 2):

Read about `add_image_size` function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/). It accepts parameters `width` in `height` in pixels, that is your problem: it doesn't accept percents. Just set any acceptable size in pixels and then style the image using CSS.

Now, you need to connect to your hosting using FTP manager, FileZilla is just fine. Open your hosting dashboard, look for FTP settings and create an FTP account for yourself. It will use host, username, password and port to connect to your server.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download your original theme and save "functions.php" of that theme.
Then, if you cannot connect via FileZilla, try to use your admin panel like cPanel or others. Go to your File Manager. When you connect your file manager, find your "functions.php" in your theme file and save it somewhere else in your computer. Then upload your original "functions.php" file to see if you get back your website. If everything is okay, go to google and search for "difference checker" and check the differences between original and changed "function.php" files. You will probably find the error.

Comment: I can't download the original theme because nothing is responding not even the admin panel. How do I download my theme?

Comment: Do you have an access to your cPanel?

Comment: Do you mean this link " www.xyz.com/wp-admin"

Comment: @UditGogoi means `www.xyz.com/cpanel` if you have cpanel hosting, if you not sure how you can access your file manager contact your web hosting provide

Comment: No, I am talking about main panel. it is like "sitename.com/cpanel". It depends on your host.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have the acess. Is there any other alternate solution

Comment: I don't think so. You have to contact with your hosting provider as @MasivuyeCokile mentioned before.